# How to change the color of content text in code behind

Tags: c#, css

I have the issue below .

I want change the color of text in Content returned to class color that derclared in my Css file.

my simple code is like this.

[

```
.alert
{
color:red;
}





public ActionResult index()
{
.
.
.
return Content("Thanks - we'll see you there!");
}
```

So, my goal is that to make "Thanks - we'll see you there!" text  to red color.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content returns just text, no html. Because it is not html you can't use CSS. You need a minimum page for your css to work:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
return Content(@"<html>
<head>
<title>Thanks!</title>
<style type="""text/css""">
.alert
{
color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="""alert""">Thanks - we'll see you there!</p>
</body>
</html>");
}
```

This way we send a complete html page to your client. But I do recommend the use of Views to make this way more readable.

Comment: Yes that's right i thank you for your response ,
But i want that if there is another short solution .. 
I suppose some thing like this .. return Contenet.SystemDrawing.Color.red("Thanks - we'll see you there!");

Comment: With content just text is sended. A clients browser doesn't know what System.Drawing is. It can only receive text. Html is text. But the browser can interpret that text to show markup. (HTML => Hyper Text Markup Language)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the controls class you can change the class like this but I don't know if there is a way to pull out individual elements of the class if you only wanted the text color.

```
ctrl.Attributes["Class"] = "redFontClass";
```

If you put the font color in its own class you can add the class as well and it should use the color

```
ctrl.Attributes.Add("Class", "redFontOnlyClass");
```

You can also do something like this if you know the color and don't want to use the whole class.

```
ctrl.Style.Add("fore-color", "red");
```

Comment: I thank you for your response , but can you make this proposition into an example to better understand.